# Trying to find this animated TV show (might be on Cartoon Network?)

Tags: story-identification, aliens, magic, cartoon

So I'm looking for this animated TV show and I cannot for the life of me remember the name. It's driving me *insane*.

The show basically goes:

- These highschoolers meet these two lizard aliens and befriend them.
- They get these magic/science/freaky-ass balls that give them each suits of armour.
- They all have specifically coloured balls (colour coded). And they wear them on their chests.
- They hang out, beat the baddies, and participate in Highschool Shenanigans™.

---

Here, have a hastily made digital sketch of the "magic armour-generating balls". Bleugh.

[image: Image Description: A hastily made digital sketch of the "magic armour-generating balls".]

*Please help me*.

Comment: When did you watch it?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots At least 4 to 5 years ago? It's not a very old cartoon though. I think.

Comment: I haven't time to write an answer (so if anybody wants to write this as an answer, feel free to do), but it is probably Supernoobs

Comment: OH YES THAT'S THE ONE.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Image search based on McTroopers comment makes it likely that Supernoobs is the answer.  The image in the question was actually very useful for confirmation.  Here's a picture.

[image: Four kids in sci-fi armour]